# How is the mass matrix formed in finite element methods?

Tags: finite-element, reference-request

I am doing a project on the finite element method. I want to know how to form the mass matrix.

Can you please point me out to the resources on the finite element method, where the procedure of assembling a mass matrix is described in detail.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! This site works best for specific, detailed questions, not such a broad request for information. Before you ask here, you should at least do a Google search ("mass matrix finite element method" yields a wealth of pertinent information) and read up on standard literature. If after that something is still unclear, you can ask a new question specifically about that.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a broad question. You can clarify what exactly you need, but basically the stiffness matrix comes from strain energy (stress times strain) and the mass matrix comes from kinetic energy (mass times velocity squared). Assembly from the elemental to global mass matrix is the same as the stiffness matrix.

Chapter 16 will be a good start.
http://www.colorado.edu/engineering/CAS/courses.d/MFEMD.d/Home.html